# Adding on to a local variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, int

Is there anyway I can make it so I can add onto a local variable as like a shortcut, for example, this loop can get a1, a2, and, a3 variables using the loopval as an add on for "a" to get the int, I hope you understand this, but, is there any way I can achieve this, using int values? Thanks.

```
   int a1 = 1;
   int a2 = 2;
   int a3 = 3;
   int loopval = 1;

   while (loopval<4) {

     System.out.println(a + loopval)


   }
```

Comment: in addition to that beeing a potential infinite loop, this wont even compile.

Comment: you could add all these values in an array and iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless you wrap the values into an array an refer to them by their `0`-based index

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int loopval = 0;

while (loopval < 3) {
   System.out.println(a[loopval++]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use arrays :

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};    
for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, it helped shorten my code by a ton. :)

Comment: @C_Tee If it helped, then don't forget to accept it.